# datetime.strptime - format matching error

Tags: python, datetime

Error: time data '6/25/17 5:00 PM' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p'

```
dateString='6/25/17 5:00 PM'
datetimeFormat = '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p'
x=datetime.datetime.strptime(dateString, datetimeFormat)
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `%Y` means full year, like 2017. you are looking for `%y` . Use this for ref: http://strftime.org/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a lower case `y` for the year, because you only have 2 digits:

```
dateString='6/25/17 5:00 PM'
datetimeFormat = '%m/%d/%y %I:%M %p'
x=datetime.datetime.strptime(dateString, datetimeFormat)

print(x) # 2017-06-25 17:00:00
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

> %y    Year without century as a zero-padded decimal number.   00, 01, ..., 99
>   %Y    Year with century as a decimal number.  0001, 0002, ..., 2013, 2014, ..., 9998, 9999    (2)